# Human somatic cells have 22 pairs of homologous chromosomes?

Tags: meiosis

I am studying for my Bio class and I am stuck with questions that I came up with during this chapter of Meiosis. I understand that human somatic cell is made up of 22 pairs of autosomes and 1 pair of sex chromosome. I am confused about what made up **each** pair of autosomes? is that 1 chromosome from the father and 1 chromosome from mother made up 1 pair of autosomes in somatic cells? and therefore, since each pair of autosomes consisted of 1 chromosome from dad and 1 from mom, we can say human somatic cells consisted of 22 pairs of homologous chromosomes (not to mention the sex of the human), right?

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler 22.5?!  You can't have half a homologous pair.  But I get what you're trying to say and it's true... There are 22 homologous pairs and half the time there is a homologous XX pair.  The other half the time there's a heterologous XY pair, though even portions of those chromosomes are homologous...

Comment: Got it! thank you so much for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

### **Answer:** *Yes  , human somatic cells have 22 pairs of homologous chromosomes

The human genome consists of 46 (2n*(22+1) ) chromosomes.

Most of our cells are **somatic** and *diploid (2n)*, they have two **homolgous chromosoms** (called homologs, one "father" & "mother") these cells multiply by *mitosis*.

Reproductiv cells or gonosomal cells, (**gametes**; Sperm and eggcell(ovum)) are the product of *meiosis* ( a part of *gametogenesis* ) . These cells are *haploid (1n)*, they only have one set of chromosomes (1n * (22+1)) which is a combination of "fater&mother". When 2 gametes  combine a diploid zygote is formed.

In both cases (Mei- and Mitosis) chromosome (pair (2n)oder single(1n)) number 1 -22 are called **autosome** , while

Chormosome number **23** is an **allosome** (sex chromosome), either Y (male) or X (female).

Since the **gametes** are haploid (1n) they have only 1 single allosome, egg cell always X , and  sperm cell either X or Y.

If the allosome (the 23 chormosome pair) of an human is *hemizygot* ( X–Y ), he is genetically male. Is the allosome pair X-X
,*homozygot* the person is genetically female.

**Somatic cells** can have therefore 22  pairs of homologous chromosomes the 22 *autosomes*. The *allosome* pair of chromosomes is not considert homologous but either "homozygot / homogametic"[XX] or "hemizygot/ hemigametic"[XY].